# What is the number of ways to distribute 14 identical balls in 3 numbered boxes, given that there has to be 8 balls in at least one of the boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've myself have deduced that the formula to be used is $\binom{k-1}{n - 1}$ where $k$ is the number of balls and $n$ is the number of boxes, which gives me $78$ possible distributions.

But the answer in the answer booklet states $84$ possible distributions. I also discovered that $14 \cdot 3!$ gives the answer $84$, but I have no idea why? Would be glad if someone explained that to me.

Also, what would be the the formula to solve the exact same question only that the condition is now that there should be **no more** than $7$ balls in each box.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

The first part of the question's intention is *at least* 8 balls in at least one box, though they should have written it more explicitly.

To solve it, we put 8 balls in one of the 3 boxes,
and distribute the remaining 6 balls in any which way applying stars and bars, thus

$3\times \binom{6+3-1}{3-1} = 84$

For the second part, we can find total unrestricted ways as $\binom{14+3-1}{3-1}$ and subtract $84$ from it.

Comment: Eureka! I finally understand it after spending a couple hours on this one problem! Thank you so much your're a lifesaver!

Comment: You're welcome !